# How to handle *args in python docstring?

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

I have a some functions in my code that are specified like this:
`def myfunction(self, *args, **kwargs):`

I need these functions to be a bit flexible on how they are called such that they will still run correctly even if some extra args or kwargs are passed in, however, each function has a specification on what args are expected/used. I would like to document those specifications in the docstring. I am currently using Google-Style docstring format. I am able to specify the `**kwargs` without any problem like this:

```
keyword Args:
    raw_args (str): raw string of arguments
    replace (bool): replace mode
```

However, for `*args`, I would like to do something similar, but I can't figure out how to do that in a way that renders nicely in pycharm. For example, I tried this:

```
Args:
    args[0] (str): filename of the python macro
    args[1] (str): character to insert
```

This does not render at all. I've also tried this:

```
Args:
    *args:
        args[0] (str): filename of the python macro
        args[1] (str): character to insert
```

This renders, but just throws everything under *args into a single line, which is not good. Is there a better way to do this? I'm open to potentially switch to a different docstring format if that would solve my problem.

Comment: If you have multiple arguments and they have different purposes, why use `*args` at all?

Comment: i think if you put 2 spaces after the `macro` word before the newline you will get a multiline string.... i think

Comment: @JoranBeasley unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: @InSync that is a reasonable question. I need the args to be optional, but I also need to be able to have an undefined number of positional args, because in some contexts, the arguments come from something that the user typed in, which may be a string that has a bunch of spaces in it. Because of that scenario, I pass the args both as positional args, and as kwargs['raw_args'], which contains the entire argument string including all of the spaces. If raw_args exist, the function will then decide wether to use the positional args or the raw_args depending on the scenario.